# Python dataframe check increment of consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a dataframe like this

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([100, 150, 150, 103])
>>> df
     0
0  100
1  150
2  150
3  103
>>>
```

I want to check if next value is less than +10% or -10% of previus value, if not replace next value with previous value

This is the desired result

```
     0
0  100
1  100
2  100
3  103
```

I tried using "where" but it doesn't work properly

```
>>> df.where(abs(df / df.shift()-1) < 0.1, df.shift().fillna(method='bfill'), inplace=True)
>>> df
     0
0  100
1  100
2  150
3  150
```

how can I solve?

Comment: in my opinion you should use a second list/dataframe; when you do the loop and you edit the current value with the previous one because +or- 10%, it will affect next iteration

Comment: are you using the `pandas` library?

Comment: yes, I'm using pandas, but like Carlo said, it could be a problem during iteration and I can't find a built-in function to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the manual loop method using [`pd.Series.iteritems`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html).

```
df = pd.DataFrame([100, 150, 150, 103])

res = np.zeros(len(df[0]))
res[0] = df[0].iloc[0]

for idx, val in df[0].iloc[1:].iteritems():
    if abs(val / res[idx-1] - 1) < 0.1:
        res[idx] = val
    else:
        res[idx] = res[idx-1]

df[1] = res.astype(int)

print(df)

     0    1
0  100  100
1  150  100
2  150  100
3  103  103
```